# ESXi 5.1 Storage vMotion

Tags: vmware-esxi

We have a 5.1 vCenter server, with several hosts, some on 5.0 and others in 5.1.

We are licensed in Standard edition.

Using the vCenter Web Client we can Storage vMotion VMs between the 5.1 hosts (with local storage).

However, using the vSphere Client (Desktop client), we can't do that, the option to 'Change both host and datastore' is grayed out with a note saying

> The virtual machine must be powered off to change the VM's host and datastore.

Any ideas on what to check? looks like a bug in the vSphere client.

Versions:

- vCenter 5.1.0, 1123961
- hosts ESXi 5.1.0, 1065491
- vSphere Client: 5.1.0 1064113

Comment: I'm not aware that you can perform a vMotion and a Storage vMotion at the same time for a powered on VM. How did you accomplish that for a running VM? I'm also not aware that you can perform a vMotion between hosts that don't share storage. How did you accomplish that? vMotion implies that this was a live migration of the VM, not a cold migration.

Comment: @joeqwerty its a new features of 5.1 - vsphere vmotion without the need of shared storage and you can do on live vm without any downtime.

Comment: I believe it is required to have vCenter for this to work. http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc%2FGUID-BBD3580E-4034-4E05-9558-D88D74E5D1D7.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do VMotion without shared storage in 5.1, it can only be done from the vSphere Web Client.

There was no more development of vSphere Client - especially the new 5.1 features.

Refer to VMware blog [here](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/09/vmotion-without-shared-storage-requirement-does-it-have-a-name.html). It seems vSphere Client is being deprecated.

And refer to the [5.1 release notes](http://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-esx-vcenter-server-51-release-notes.html):

> *vSphere Client. In vSphere 5.1, **all new vSphere features are available only through the vSphere Web Client**. The traditional vSphere Client will continue to operate, supporting the same feature set as vSphere 5.0, but not exposing any of the new features in vSphere 5.1.*

Comment: This is true, sadly enough..

Comment: Yet you can only do update manager config via the vsclient still, and SSO is broken - not happy with 5.1 at all

Comment: SSO was fixed in the meantime (with 5.1 U1a), and the Update Manager integration of the Web Client got much better with 5.1 U1 (although not yet complete).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not a good choice in my opinion... but I guess they (VMware) know better than me.

Comment: to get web client I must download and run the install of vcenter server? http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50%2FGUID-74AA3EF1-BDF3-4752-89DB-A522CDE30A66.html

Comment: @scape - yes, vcenter is needed to use the web client.